# How can I run MLJ model on GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, gpu

Is there any way to run `MLJLinearmodel` on GPU?

## Example

```
using MLJ
X = MLJ.table(rand(100, 10));
y = 2X.x1 - X.x2 + 0.05*rand(100);

@load LinearRegressor pkg=MLJLinearModels verbosity=0;
model = LinearRegressor()

mach = machine(model, X, y);
fit!(mach)

params = fitted_params(mach)
params.coefs # coefficient of the regression with names
params.intercept # intercept

Xnew  = MLJ.table(rand(3, 10));
ypred = predict(mach, Xnew)
```

This is something I took from the [documentation](https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/MLJLinearModels.jl/dev/quickstart/).

Please suggest, how may I train this model on GPU.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first sentence refers to `MLJLinearModel`, but your example refers to `DecisionTreeRegressor`...

Comment: @CameronBieganek Apologies!! In the mid I decided to change and forgot that part, haha i will fix it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a built in way to run `MLJLinearModels` on the GPU, but you might be able to make it happen by combining the right packages.